# Identificar o nome das ruas contidas em um polígono

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Tenho o seguinte polígono abaixo:

```js
function initialize() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i;

  var polygonCoords = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(-23.554548, -46.607911),
     new google.maps.LatLng(-23.556043, -46.595058),
     new google.maps.LatLng(-23.564403, -46.593942),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.567884, -46.604757)
  ];
  

  for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
     bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: bounds.getCenter(),
    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
  });


  var sp_mooca = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  sp_mooca.setMap(map);
 
  
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas2" style="height: 100vh; width:100vw"></div>
</body>
```

É possível identificar o nome de todas as ruas contidas em um polígono no Google Maps? Se sim, como?!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a API não possua um método que retorne endereços num polígono.

Tem o `containsLocation` que verifica se a coordenada está dentro do polígono. Se a sua intenção é extrair os endereços do polígono para verificar se bate com algum endereço que você tem, pode fazer o caminho contrário: verifique se os seus endereços pertencem ao polígono.

E tem o `geocode` que retorna o endereço a partir de uma coordenada. Então você pode fazer um loop percorrendo coordenadas dentro do polígono obtendo os endereços. Mas dessa forma você pode atingir o limite de queries facilmente. [Exemplo de código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209879/1840019).

Acho que de certa forma, dependendo do tamanho do polígono, isso caracterizaria extração em massa da API, o que é proibido pelos termos de uso. Você pode usar o OpenStreetMap para isso, e até baixar o database (dá pra selecionar apenas uma região) e fazer as manipulações de geodata sem restrições.